# Google Sheets API does not append rows PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, curl, google-api

I'm trying to append rows inside a Google Sheet in onedrive thanks to a bot which make a curl call to an API.
I tried in local with 1013 rows and it works perfectly. But then in production, there is no rows appended inside the same Google sheet. I check the response of the method append and there is no error. I don't know what information to give to you to resolve it.
There is my code :

```
    //print_r($clients);
    // Récupération du Client API Google JT
    $client = ExtractionManager::getClient();
    $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    try {
        $spreadsheetId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // id du document google sheet test client
        // Create the value range Object
        $valueRange = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
        // You need to specify the values you insert
        //$valueRange->setValues($clients);
        $valueRange->setValues($clients);
        // Then you need to add some configuration
        $conf = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW'];
        // mettre le nom de l(onglet que vous optenner dans le googlesheet
        $range = 'Sheet1';
        // Update the spreadsheet
        $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump('Message: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return json_encode([
        'Nombre de client ajoute' => ($result->updates->updatedRows == null)?0:$result->updates->updatedRows,
        'Nombre de client a ajouter' => count($clients)
    ]);
```

And there is the response :

```
Google\Service\Sheets\AppendValuesResponse Object
(
[spreadsheetId] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[tableRange] => Sheet1!A1:K1
[updatesType:protected] => Google\Service\Sheets\UpdateValuesResponse
[updatesDataType:protected] =>
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[updates] => Google\Service\Sheets\UpdateValuesResponse Object
    (
        [spreadsheetId] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [updatedCells] =>
        [updatedColumns] =>
        [updatedDataType:protected] => Google\Service\Sheets\ValueRange
        [updatedDataDataType:protected] =>
        [updatedRange] => Sheet1!A2
        [updatedRows] =>
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: What's the error.  What you have posted is not an error message.

Comment: The thing is that the API does not append the 1013 rows and in the response there is no error message so I don't understand why nothing is appended... It works in localhost

Comment: consider then what is the difference between your production and test environments?  Where's your authorization code.

Comment: Here is the connection to the client

Comment: `private static function getClient()
 {
  $client = new \Google_Client(['api_format_v2'=> true]);
  $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API JT Extraction');
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');
  $client->setAuthConfig(PRJ_PATH . 'credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  //$client->setAccessToken('43c6abdc3e11ac1291662d4e80f218735fd3af78');

  return $client;
 }`

Comment: Is there a solution?